# Troubleshooting: 'The .NET Core SDK cannot be located.' errors On Linux Mint XFCE

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I was trying to use vs code with unity but it showed this message

`The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.`

I tried to install with this code
`./dotnet-install.sh -c Current`

and showed up this
`dotnet-install: .NET Core SDK with version '6.0.302' is already installed.`

but when i tried to see if it realy worked:
`dotnet --version dotnet: comando não encontrado`

Comment: There’s so much this could be.   Are you sure that’s the right sdk. Are you sure dotnet is pathed.

Comment: It seem like dotnet binary is not add command line. Are you use bash or sh ?